# Should I capitalise short phrases of dialogue in the middle of a sentence?

Tags: capitalization, dialogue

> He chanted "activate" to activate his powers.

or

> He chanted "Activate" to activate his powers.

This question is specifically for short phrases, not entire sentences.

Comment: No, the quotations are there to separate the word from the rest of the sentence.

Comment: For example, see [quotations](https://writingcenter.unc.edu/tips-and-tools/quotations/).

Comment: Your words are not part of sentences, so unless they are titles or names (proper nouns), they should be in lowercase.

Comment: @JasonBassford But what if it could be a sentence in its own right, such as "With a brief 'game over, kid' she left the room." Would you capitalise in this case?

Comment: You always capitalize the first letter of the first word of any actual sentence, in narrative or dialogue. But in *With a brief "game over, kid" she left the room*, "game over, kid" is not a sentence. However, in *She said, "Game over kid," and left the room*, "Game over kid" is a sentence—because the dialogue tag is being used. The context determines if it's just a phrase, a sentence, or something actually descriptive. (The sign read *Do not enter.*)

Comment: @JasonBassford So what defines a sentence? Surely "game over, kid" was a complete sentence to the person it was being said to?